# tomcat maven plugin t7mp

Tags: tomcat, maven

I got it to run with the instruction on the site, but after that I am clueless. Does anybody konw the goals to deploy, undeploy, list server info etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin only has 3 goals: run, stop and stop-server.

To get more information out of this, run `mvn help:describe -Dplugin=t7 -Ddetail`.